# how to build one to many rows in tokyo cabinet?

Tags: primary-key, tokyo-cabinet, dht

i quote from the tokyo cabinet docs...

> As for database of hash table, each key must be unique within a database,
>   so it is impossible to store two or more records with a key overlaps.

or does tokyocabinet allow tuple based keys ?

what would be the best way to set a one-to-many store ( like a crawler 1 kw<->many docids )

~B

Answer (score 1):

Using the table database (TDB), you can simply store a list of keys in one value as tokens. As long as your keys are valid "tokens", you can easily list them this way in a single field.

Here's an example using [Pyrant](http://code.google.com/p/pyrant)'s low-level interface:

```
>>> from pyrant import Tyrant
>>> t = Tyrant()
>>> includes = 5  # code for operation TDBQCSTROR
>>> t['test'] = {'foo': 'abc,def', 'bar': 'abc def', 'quux': 'abcdef'}
>>> t.proto.search([('foo',includes,'abc')])
[u'test']
>>> t.proto.search([('bar',includes,'abc')])
[u'test']
>>> t.proto.search([('quux',includes,'abc')])
[]
>>> t.proto.search([('quux',includes,'abcd')])
[]
>>> t.proto.search([('quux',includes,'abcdef')])
[u'test']
```

TDBQCSTROR is an operation type which stands for "string includes at least one token in..." (see "tctdbqryaddcond" in [Tokyo Cabinet API specs](http://tokyocabinet.sourceforge.net/spex-en.html#tchdbapi)).

Note that both "abc,def" and "abc def" matched the "abc" keyword, but "abcdef" didn't, despite "abc" is actually subset of "abcdef". This can be used to search keys stored in a single string, e.g.:

```
t['tokyocabinet'] = {'title': 'Tokyo Cabinet'}
t['primary-key'] = {'title': 'Primary Key'}
t['question1228313'] = {
    'title': 'how to build one to many rows in tokyo cabinet?',
    'tags': 'tokyocabinet, primary-key',
}
```

(Tags are probably not the best example as they don't need to be references.)

If you are using a TC database of another kind (not TDB), I cannot imagine a valid solution. You may want to ask this question in the related [discussion group](http://groups.google.com/group/tokyocabinet-users/).

Answer (score 0):

*As for database of hash table, each key must be unique within a database, so it is impossible to store two or more records with a key overlaps.*

B+ -Tree Tokyo Cabinet databases allow duplicate keys:

```
bool tcbdbputdup(TCBDB *bdb, const void *kbuf, int ksiz, const void *vbuf, int vsiz);
```

Using the Ruby API:

```
TokyoCabinet::BDB.putdup(key, value) -> true|false
TokyoCabinet::BDB.getlist(key) => [value, ...]|nil
```